# How to poll a set of APIs from an angular app?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to poll a set of APIs from an angular app.

This is my code:

```
// service

subscribeToData(response: any): Observable<any> {
    const requests = [];
    response.forEach(item => {
        requests.push(this.startPolling(item.href).pipe(catchError(err => of('error'))));
    });
    return forkJoin(requests);
}

private startPolling(api: string): Observable<any> {
    return timer(0, 1000)
      .switchMap(() => this.httpClient.get(api));
}

// component
this.service.subscribeToData(response).subscribe(data => {
    // do something
})
```

In the browser network console, I can see that the requests are getting triggered and completed but the subscriber is not getting invoked.

Is the way I'm doing this correct or is there some other way?

Comment: You mean  `subscribe(data => {
    // do something
})` is not running?

Comment: Yes, even though I can see that network requests are getting completed.

Comment: Try log both complete and error callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of reading around, the `forkJoin` does not return until all the observables inside it complete: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Since in this case `forkJoin` contains timers, I assume they never complete.

It started working after I replaced `forkJoin` with `combineLatest`
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html